# ES6 Destructuring dates

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to destructure dates?

I know for objects you can do something like this.

```
var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var {p, q} = o;

console.log(p); // 42
console.log(q); // true
```

Is there a better way to do the following in ES6? Does something like object destructuring exist for this?

```
function getFormattedDate(date) {
    return `${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
}
```

Comment: If the properties are functions and need to be called, destructuring isn't really an option.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you already have?

Comment: You should not be formatting dates yourself. Instead, use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) with a locale of `en-US`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my code. I was just wondering if there is a feature I'm missing or don't know about since it feels very similar to object destructuring.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an object that inherits from the `Date` object, add getters for month, day, and year, and then you can destructure it. Although it has some overhead, this might be worthwhile if you use dates a lot. In addition, you can fix things, like the need to add 1 to month.

> Although you can add the getters directly to the `Date` object, this
>   is a bad practice. You can more about it in this thread - [**Why is
>   extending native objects a bad practice?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice).

```js
class EDate extends Date {  
  get month() {
    return this.getMonth() + 1;
  }
  
  get day() {
    return this.getDate();
  }
  
  get year() {
    return this.getFullYear();
  }
}

const getFormattedDate = ({ month, day, year }) => `${month}/${day}/${year}`

console.log(getFormattedDate(new EDate()));

// since Date can receive another Date as input, you can do this as well

const date = new Date();

console.log(getFormattedDate(new EDate(date)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes you can destructure Date(), but youre only limited to a few methods.

```
    let {now,UTC,parse} = Date, {log} = console;

    //returns current time in milliseconds
    log(now());

    //returns a date format for UTC
    log(UTC(96, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

    //parses a date to milliseconds
    log(parse('04 Dec 1995 00:12:00 GMT'));
```

These are the only methods that CAN be deconstructed without defenition.  Methods like `getMonth()`, `getYear()`, and the like HAVE to have a `new Date` defined.  However you can calculate instead what milliseconds convert to (say `now()/1000` returns `seconds`). But having an ACCURATE conversion will be a challenge.